# jquerymobile slider and broken step attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I've got a very strange problem. Since two hours Im trying to make slider steps just like here http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/slider/ but it doesn't works.

```
<label for="slider-0">Input slider:</label>
<input type="range" name="slider-1" id="slider-0" value="25" min="0" max="100" step="5" />
```

I suppose that all is about different jquerymobile version but Im using default code from page http://jquerymobile.com/download/

still doesn't works :(

even adding this (http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js">
```

can anyone paste in answers working code?

best regards

Answer (score 0):

This Bug has been Fixed in Latest version JQuery Mobile Libraries mentioned below

1)stable version - 1.0.1
  http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/01/26/jquery-mobile-1-0-1-released/

2)Unstable build - 1.1.0 RC1 
  http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/02/28/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-1-0-rc1/